# Why i am getting step wise output in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written the code for getting total in this list but i am getting a step wise output

```
ram_list = [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555]

sham_list = [6666, 7777, 8888, 9999, 909]

total = 0

for item in ram_list:

    total = total + item

    print(total)
```

o/p

```
1111

3333

6666

11110

16665
```

Required o/p

```
16665
```

Comment: Put the print statement outside the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your print statement

```
for item in ram_list:

    total = total + item

    print(total) //This one
```

is inside the for loop. This causes it to print the total at every iteration. If you want only the final value, put the print statement outside the for loop.

```
ram_list = [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555]

sham_list = [6666, 7777, 8888, 9999, 909]

total = 0

for item in ram_list:

    total = total + item

// Like this
print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. it really helpd me

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could be of help. Don't forget to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers